# sp_executesql not using index?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, count

I'm using nHibnerate in my web application and I have a problem using indexes in generated sp_execute. My table has 210 millions records and the query is very slow.

Firstly, there was a problem with generated column 'kolumna1' type. In database I have a column of varchar but nHibernate generated nvarchar. I workarounded this by putting special attribute in the code which forced using varchar. After that trick sp_executed started using indexes and everything was correct. Now the problem is back sp_executesql takes 10 minutes to finish. When i checked normal query(without sp_executesql) it took only 1s. I checked execution plans for both: sp_executesql wasn't using index and normal query was using index. Without changing index i modified back varchar to nvarchar and sp_execute finished in 1s (used index). Anyone got any idea where did i make a mistake ? why the execution plan is diffrent for such small changes? And how to fix it?

Here i attached more code. Just in case if someone need it.

**sp_executesql with varchar(8000)**

```
exec  sp_executesql N'SELECT count(*) as y0_  FROM tabela1 this_ WHERE ((this_.kolumna2 >= @p0 and this_.kolumna2 <= @p1)) and  
    (this_.kolumna3 in (@p2, @p3) and this_.kolumna1 like @p4)',N'@p0 datetime,@p1 datetime,@p2 int,@p3 int,@p4 varchar(8000)',
    @p0='2013-01-08 14:38:00' ,@p1='2013-02-08 14:38:00',@p2=341,@p3=342,@p4='%501096109%'
```

[image: sp_executesql with varchar]

**sp_executesql with nvarchar(4000)**

```
exec  sp_executesql N'SELECT count(*) as y0_  FROM tabela1 this_ WHERE ((this_.kolumna2 >= @p0 and this_.kolumna2 <= @p1)) and  
    (this_.kolumna3 in (@p2, @p3) and this_.kolumna1 like @p4)',N'@p0 datetime,@p1 datetime,@p2 int,@p3 int,@p4 nvarchar(4000)',
    @p0='2013-01-08 14:38:00' ,@p1='2013-02-08 14:38:00',@p2=341,@p3=342,@p4='%501096109%'
```

[image: sp_executesql with nvarchar]

The funny part is that in sql profiler both query gives same reuslt:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT count(*) as y0_ FROM tabela1 this_  
WHERE this_.kolumna3 in (@p2, @p3) and ((this_.kolumna2 >= @p0 and this_.kolumna2 <= @p1))  
and ( this_.kolumna1 like @p4)',N'@p0 datetime,@p1 datetime,@p2 int,@p3 int,@p4 varchar(8000)',  
@p0='2013-01-08 14:38:00' ,@p1='2013-02-08 14:38:00',@p2=341,@p3=342,@p4='%501096109%'  
--Declare @p0 datetime  
--set @p0 = '2013-01-08 14:38:00'  
--Declare @p1 datetime  
--set @p1 = '2013-02-08 14:38:00'  
--Declare @p2 int  
--set @p2 = 341  
--Declare @p3 int  
--set @p3 = 342  
--Declare @p4 varchar(8000)  
--set @p4 = '%501096109%'  
--SELECT count(*) as y0_  
 --FROM tabela1 this_  
 --WHERE ((this_.kolumna2 >= @p0 and  
 --this_.kolumna2 <= @p1)) and  
 --(this_.kolumna3 in (@p2, @p3) and this_.kolumna1 like @p4)
```

Here are indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tabela1](
[id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[kolumna1] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
[kolumna2] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[kolumna3] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK__tabela1__4F7CD00D] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ind_tabela1_ kolumna2] ON [dbo].[tabela1] 
(
    [kolumna2] ASC

)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ind_ tabela1_ kolumna3] ON [dbo].[ tabela1] 
(
    [kolumna3] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ tabela1_ kolumna1] ON [dbo].[ tabela1] 
(
    [kolumna1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ tabela1_ kolumna2_ kolumna3] ON [dbo].[ tabela1] 
(
    [kolumna2] ASC,
    [kolumna3] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ tabela1_ kolumna3_ kolumna2_id_ kolumna1] ON [dbo].[ tabela1] 
(
    [kolumna3] ASC,
    [kolumna2] ASC,
    [id] ASC,
    [kolumna1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Below execution plan for query: select count(*) from [dbo].[tabela1] where [kolumna1] like N'%501096109%'
[image: execution plan for query]

Comment: This may help: http://is.gd/RR0fzH

Comment: This query will not be able to use an index seek for kolumna1. Reason is you've got a leading % in your pattern. Can you provide the non-count query that does use one of your indexes?

Comment: To Jamie Ide: We have already tried this approach and we have both varchar in nhibernate and databse

Comment: To muhmu: We have alwase been using count query. I've made a mistake in my question. I already have fixed it and added execution plans for nvarchar and varchar query.

Comment: Are you saying that the query that produces the first execution plan is the same as the query you've given, just without using sp_executesql? Could you verify this? Because the plan contains an index seek on IX_tabela1_kolumna1, but, as I said before, your query contains a pattern for kolumna1 that doesn't allow this. Also, can you provide the whole first plan? It's got chopped a bit. It would also be nice if you would put the actual SQL you used above each plan.

Comment: Thanks for respond muhmud. You got a point. I'll check query again and change execution plans on monday.

Comment: Ok. i fixed the post. If you need further information please feel free to ask.

Comment: Still shows index seek. If you run `select count(*) from [dbo].[tabela1] where [kolumna1] like '%501096109%'`, and look at the plan, does it show a seek?

Comment: no it's not using index seek

Comment: I made mistake. Following query: select count(*) from [dbo].[tabela1] where [kolumna1] like '%501096109%' uses index seek.

Comment: And the index is IX_tabela1_kolumna1? Also, what does the plan for `select count(*) from [dbo].[tabela1] where [kolumna1] like N'%501096109%'` do? (Notice the N)

Comment: I've added execution plan in post. It took like 10min to finish query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25080/discussion-between-muhmud-and-jan-salawa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql Server query optimizer can choose to use index seek when:

1. There are another filter predicates besides LIKE. It should be a precise search or at least SARGable predicate
2. Table is very large (millions of rows)

But seek operation cannot be done when explicit type conversion is used - different collation/datatype.
Another thing that you cannot control this behavior and query plans can be vary for different predicate sets. To do this, you need to use hint FORCESEEK (version 2008+). You can find information here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply. Ok, but how to force NHibernate to use hints? Our query conditions have the same collation/dataType like included parameters. For tests I put after query in sp_executeSQL Option(Recompile) and It works.

Comment: Please look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085450/jpa-entity-use-index-hint)

Answer (score 2):

Could you try this:

(1) Run the following SQL:

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) t
```

(2) Use the last column to find the SQL for the first query. It will not contain sp_executesql, but will start with your list of parameters, the last one being a varchar. Get the `plan_handle`, and use it in the following statement:

```
dbcc freeproccache (<your_plan_handle>)
```

Then retry query 1.